# Is Undertow able to use the same IO worker Thread to handle two different requests?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, undertow

Here is my situation where I have writen a demo, which will send two different requests to my server at the same time.

**Normally:**
Undertow will use two XNIO worker threads

```
[   XNIO-1 I/O-3    XNIO-1 I/O-4]
```

to handle these two requests:

```
2018-11-30 12:42:10.408  INFO 13052 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-3] com.ecarx.asrapi.handler.ASRHandler      : ======收到Up请求, id=18179c3d-8958-4ca2-b5a1-65d0f73991da, ak=8c3d8bde3d94397e539dd6eff6e0318336db8e30=======

2018-11-30 12:42:11.896  INFO 13052 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-4] com.ecarx.asrapi.handler.ASRHandler      : ======收到Down请求, id=18179c3d-8958-4ca2-b5a1-65d0f73991da, ak=8c3d8bde3d94397e539dd6eff6e0318336db8e30=======
```

[image: Normal snapshot]

**Abnormal:**
Undertow uses the same IO worker thread

```
[   XNIO-1 I/O-3]
```

to handle my different requests:

```
2018-11-30 12:42:24.253  INFO 13052 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-3] com.ecarx.asrapi.handler.ASRHandler      : ======收到Up请求, id=4b16a94a-7cc0-4904-ae2b-aae63093ed25, ak=91349ab08e093314705cb59872a206f25f3502bb=======

2018-11-30 12:42:25.737  INFO 13052 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-3] com.ecarx.asrapi.handler.ASRHandler      : ======收到Down请求, id=4b16a94a-7cc0-4904-ae2b-aae63093ed25, ak=91349ab08e093314705cb59872a206f25f3502bb=======
```

[image: Abnormal snapshot]

**Demo:** likely to send two different requests:

```
    String url = config.getUrl();
    executor.execute(() -> handleUpStream(url + "/up?id=" + id + "&ak=" + token, type, data));
    //handle down stream
    executor.execute(() -> handleDownStream(url + "/down?id=" + id + "&ak=" + token, responses));
```

**Hanlders:**

```
@PostMapping(value = "up", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public Mono<Object> handleASRUp(@RequestParam(required = false) String id, @RequestParam String ak, ServerHttpRequest request) {// need more time to handle...}


@PostMapping(value = "down", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public Mono<Void> handleASRDown(@RequestParam String id, @RequestParam String ak, ServerHttpResponse response) {//need a little time to handle...}
```

Comment: Could you improve your question? Could you tell us what you're trying to achieve, show us a code snippet of how you're trying to do that, what result did you expect and what are you seeing instead. Thanks!

Comment: OK. Here is what I wanna say, I use a demo send two Http requests to server, well, in server side, sometime, server[Undertow] will use two different IO-Threads to handle the two requests, and somehow, server JUST use the same one single IO-Thread hanlde my two different Http requests.

As the snapshots put it, my "Up" request firstly coming and being handled, but NOT finished, then "Down" coming, the server will hang "Up" request, and start to hanlde "down" request, when "Down" is finished, then server start to handle "Up" request.

Comment: What I expect is server should finish "Up" and "Down" with two different  IO-Thread, Not the same one.

Comment: Could you update your question with that information? How are you triggering the different cases? Is that a different application? A different type of request? Could you show some code snippets demonstrating how is the server setup and what the request handlers look like?

Comment: Will you help to check the first snapshot, that is normal case, recevies "up" and "down" request with two different NIO; But the second snapshot receives "up" and "down" request within the same one Single NIO thread.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am guess may the NIO number issue, for I set server.undertow.io-threads = 1, server will always use one single NIO thread to handle my "up" and "down" requests at the same time, hang up "up" request and handle "down" request though.
But I do NOT understand why server does NOT block "Down" request outside, after "up" request was finished, then start to handle "down" request; After all, "Up request" was first arrived.